# The Type or namespace "Filters" does not exists in the current context Error in MVC4

Tags: model-view-controller

As I'm using Visual studio 2012 I'm getting this error while using Microsoft.Filters.AuthenticationFilters

I have installed microsoft.filters in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using *Visual Studio 2012*, You have access to 4 types of filters.

1. Authorization filters.
2. Action filters.
3. Result filters.
4. Exception filters.

Authentication filter is a new filter added in the new version of ASP.Net.

**Go through the link for more information.**

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/filters-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Then how I can Authenticate filter in my project?

Comment: The Authorization filters works for your project.
it Performs authentication and authorizes before executing an action method.